# How to represent custom JSONField out as comma-seperated string in Django Admin list page?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-3.2

Consider I have a Django model with a custom **`JSONField`** as below,

```py
# models.py

class JSONCustomField(models.JSONField):
    ...


class JSONFieldModel(models.Model):
    json_field = JSONCustomField(default=list)
```

This model is connected via Django Admin

```py
# admin.py

@admin.register(JSONFieldModel)
class JSONFieldModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def expected_json(self: JSONFieldModel):
        return self.json_field

    list_display = ("id", "json_field", expected_json)
```

This setup resulting an output  like the below,

[image: Current Output]

#### Questions

- Why `JSON FIELD` and `EXPECTED JSON` display different results in Django Admin? (It's supposed to be the same, right?)
- How can I tell Django to parse and display my *"list of strings"* to *"comma separated strings"* as `EXPECTED JSON` represents? That is, how to tell Django to give me result as `EXPECTED JSON` while adding the custom field to the ModelAdmin as a string (*"json_field"*) in Django Admin

#### Notes

- Django version `3.2.X`
- Assume that the `json_field` will only accept `list` inputs (Just like an `ArrayField`)

Comment: do you need to change the data in the database or only in the admin panel?

Comment: Both. But, how does that relevant to the OP? @inquirer

Comment: What is OP? If the data needs to be changed in the database, then they will change in the admin panel. I roughly know how to turn a list into a string separated by commas. If so, let me know.

Comment: If you look at the image, I was getting the expected result with a custom setup (`expected_json`/`EXPECTED JSON`) using `expected_json(...)` function. But, Django not giving the same result when I mention the field name (`json_field`/`JSON FIELD`)

Comment: I'm happy to see the solution that doesn't add custom column methods (just like `expected_json(...)`) to the `ModelAdmin`/`JSONFieldModelAdmin`.